# Java annotation putting parameter constraint on a method in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, parameters, annotations

As you all know, with reflection you are able to check if an annotated method has the required parameters. Is it possible to set something up so that, in my IDE (Netbeans) it validates wether said annotated method has the required parameters and would highlight it as an error or warning should the method not meet the requirements of the annotation?

Example:

```
@Manifest (decoder = GameDecoder.class, opcode = 12, size = 0)
public class PingRequest {

    @Incoming
    public void receive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buf) {

    }

    @Outgoing
    public void prepare(ByteBuf bb) {

    }

}
```

Those two methods NEED to have the specified parameters, however you can type the methods without those parameters and Netbeans will as expected not say anything because it's not wrong however during runtime they wouldn't get used because they don't have the required parameters.

I did it like this so that my networking is completely POJO but if Netbeans cannot tell me the required parameters in such annotated methods then I might use an interface or something to specify a "contract" that states those methods NEED to have those parameters.

Comment: The proper way in Java to specify a contract for a class is to define an interface, and make the class implement that interface. You should do that. The compiler will check that the class has all the required methods, with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: I don't think any IDE allows the kind of checks. You can use interfaces as said by JB Nizet or just throw an exception at runtime.

Comment: You could also write an annotation processor, but it's a much more complex task than using an interface.

Comment: Alright. It was more of a creative... test. It would also be overcomplicating things. Thanks guys! Interface it is :)

Comment: @Limnic You should also step back and figure at which point in time checking takes place. There are only few annotations that deal with compile time; and surprise: those need to be implemented **within** the compiler. Anything else happens at **runtime**. How would you expect your IDE can do "runtime" like tests ... if nothing is running?